# Get data from DB after flush and before commit

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to insert a record in IBM DB2 DB. Upon insertion, a timestamp field is auto-generated. I have to take this value and send it via Kafka. I can only commit transaction if Kafka is successful, otherwise I rollback.

I am inserting using a native "INSERT" query.

**REQUIREMENT**: Want to get the auto-generated timestamp value without committing, so that I can rollback easily.

I tried flushing but that did not work.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

session.flush() will work and get you the data if you query your DB. But these changes may not be visible in your Database visualizer (like Teradata) until you commit your transactions.

Hope that helped.